# link tfs work item to different project

Tags: tfs

In VS Team 2010, is there a way to link a work item from Project A to a work item in Project B?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to the All Links tab of the work item
2. Click the Link to button. This will open a dialog
3. Click the Browse... button next to the Work Item IDs label. This will open up a
   new dialog
4. At the top of this dialog, you can change the Project